# Creating children records: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting the dreaded error: "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" when I access the "new" action for one of my controllers. The error occurs when I access /works/new. A User has_many Works. Here is the Works controller:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @works = Work.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @works }
end

def create
@work = current_user.works.build(params[:works])
    if @work.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'home'
    end
  end

def new
  @work = Work.new
end

def destroy
  @work.destroy
  redirect_to root_url
end

end
  def show
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
end
```

In the new.html.erb view file I'm using the following loop to create a form so that submitting the filled out fields will create a new Work record for the User:

```
 <%= form_for(@work) do |f| %>
```

I have a feeling that this is the source of the error since I'm not telling Rails to create the new Work with the User relationship in mind. Am I correct in assuming that this is the issue? If so, how do I fix the above loop?

Comment: You say you're using "the following loop", but I don't see a loop. Did you forget to paste some code or did you just mean "block"?

Comment: Sorry about that, you are correct. I meant to type "block" instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend changing your new method so that it scopes the Work object to the current user. I'm not sure that is your problem though...

```
def new
  @work = current_user.works.new
end
```

**Update:**

It looks like your method definitions are screwed up in the controller. `create`, `new`, and `destroy` are actually being defined within your `index` method. You need to move the `end` that is right above the `show` method to be right above the `create` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's a good idea but unfortunately I'm still getting the error. I'm sure making this change saved me from future bugs, however!

Comment: Is the stacktrace showing that line as being the one causing problems?

Comment: The stacktrace shows that this line in the view is causing the error:    <%= form_for(@work) do |f| %>

Comment: just posted an update to my question, looks like a syntax issue.